# Interpretation results seasonality in data R

Tags: r

I have a question about the results that I get from checking whether my data contains seasonality or not.
I have a csv file which contains date, period and year. However, R reads the date as a factor and I didn't know how to deal with is. 
So I extracted the frequencies per month, so I have very little points now.

My code:

```
k <- c(1110,989,1141,674,790,739,842,1004,751,765,1246,1045,
       1106,1078,1012,965,978,991,856,703,784,639,821,518)

z <- ts(k, start =c(2012,1), frequency =12)

plot(decompose(z))
```

[image]

I really don't know how to read this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not knowing how to interpret a plot isn't really a specific programming question and therefore isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help understanding statistical methods, you should be posting to [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Please don't cross poss questions. Pick the best site for your question. If you later decide it belongs elsewhere, flag it and ask for it to be migrated. Otherwise we just end up with duplicated posts when someone else migrates it. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: how can I delete this one?